# Style of tabulation : replace spaces by dots

Tags: apache-flex

For a multiple choice questions, I would like to format text like this :

> Answer............................A
>   LongAnswer....................B
>   VeryVeryVeryVeryLong
>   Answer............................C

(Display in a RichText or a Label)

Data come from an XML like this :

```
<answer_a>Answer</answer_a>
<answer_b>LongAnswer</answer_b>
 ...
```

I tried with 3 labels in horizontal layout for each lines but it doesn't work for the third case.

Now I use tabStops for alignment, it work well, but I can't find how to replace spaces by dots in a proper way.

Answer (score 0):

Hum, interesting problem. Personally, I think I would put your answers in a `DataGroup` with an item renderer that would show the answer to the right and answer label to the left, then by overriding the `updateDisplayList` function, I would draw points (1 pixel 'squares') from the leftmost text to the rightmost.  However, for that third possibility, it would be a lot more difficult to achieve.  I can't think of a good way right now.

Comment: Thank for your reply, I retain your suggestion about the overriding of updateDisplayList, it's cleaner than what I had done, and hopefully closer to the solution.